# RESTKit,JSONKit, json-framework - are these library interchangeable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

[JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit),[RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit),[json-framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) - are these library interchangeable? When to use each of them or it's enough to know only about RestKit(seems more popular and documented)

Comment: Depends. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you cited do different things.

`JSONKit` and `json-framework` are two JSON libraries.

`RestKit` is a framework providing object mapping between Objective-C objects and RESTful web services.

To answer your question, `JSONKit`, `json-framework`, `NSJSONSerialization` and so on are interchangeable since they provide the same set of functionalities: encoding/decoding JSON data, whereas `RestKit` is a complete different thing.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using **NSJSONSerialization** simply because it's now built into the foundation framework, which means it will *always be supported and for the most part be backward compatible (though, this is Apple so no promises on that). It also really helps layout an understanding of which objects can be serialized currently in objective c.

- The top level object is an **NSArray** or **NSDictionary**.
- All objects are instances of **NSString**, **NSNumber**, **NSArray**,
  **NSDictionary**, or **NSNull**.
- All dictionary keys are instances of **NSString**.
- Numbers are not **NaN** or infinity.

[NSJSONSerialization Class Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

*nothing is forever. :)